# PHP Get User Info Safe?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, global, user-accounts

On my ecommerce website I want to display users' names if they're logged in. I'm a noobie at php, but I wrote a little something and put it in a static file (pretty much wrapper header).

```
<li class="menu-item">
        <a href="https://mywebsite.com/my-account">
        <?php
            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
               global $current_user;
                   get_currentuserinfo();
                    if ( ! $current_user->user_firstname == 0 ) {
                        echo 'Hi, ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '!';
                } else {
                    echo 'Hi, Friend';
                };
            } else {
                echo 'My Account';
            };      
        ?>
        </a>
    </li>
```

Is this safe--retrieving user info and displaying it in the header? I'm worried about this user info being accessible to the malicious.

Do I need to write it differently? Should it be in functions.php?

Thanks for your genius!

Sincerely,
Js

Comment: You could add it as a function and return the value or false if not found. Just remember to escape the output. You can’t trust everything that the users type in.

Comment: And `get_currentuserinfo()` has been deprecated so you should user `wp_get_current_user()`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/